# CosmoDB querying a value within an array using Mongo driver does not seem possible

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb

We are migrating from mongoDB to CosmoDB using the Mongo Java Client. We have encountered the following difference in query behavior with arrays.

We have documents that look something like the following

```
[{
    "name":"garry",
    "pets":["cats","dogs"]
},
{
    "name":"sally",
    "pets":["cats","fish"]
}]
```

using mongo a query for
`find({"pets":"cats"})`

will return `garry` and `sally` however using cosmoDB we get zero results.
Is there a way to modify the query to replicate the same mongo behavior?

We also have documents that look something like the following that we query on type

`[{
        "name": "garry",
        "pets": [{
            "type": "cat",
            "name": "Mittens"
        }, {
            "type": "dog",
            "name": "Max"
        }]
    },
    {
        "name": "sally",
        "pets": [{
            "type": "cat",
            "name": "Paul"
        }, {
            "type": "fish",
            "name": "Bubbles"
        }]
    }
]`

current mongo queries look like
`find({"pets.type": "fish"})`

in

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the query below, it works.

1. Using MongoShell.

   ```
   find({"pets": {$all: ["cats"]}})
   ```
2. For Mongo Java Driver

   ```
   FindIterable<Document> queryResult = collection.find(Filters.all("pets", "cats"));
   ```

Comment: The $all query works when the target is an array. Is there a way to query if the target is within an additional array without having to change the path? I had success with $elemMatch queries `{"pets": {$elemMatch:{"type":"fish"}}}` however this requires changing the path as-well as a much greater understanding of the document structure. I added an example documents to the question.